# GROUP BY + ORDER BY make my query very slow

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, query-optimization

I am trying to figure out what I should do to my query and/ or to my tables structure to improve a query to get the best sellers which is run in over 1 sec.

Here is the query I'm talking about:

```
SELECT pr.id_prod, MAX(pr.stock) AS stock, MAX(pr.dt_add) AS dt_add, SUM(od.quantity) AS quantity
    FROM orders AS o
    INNER JOIN orders_details AS od ON od.id_order = o.id_order
    INNER JOIN products_references AS pr ON pr.id_prod_ref = od.id_prod_ref
    INNER JOIN products AS p ON p.id_prod = pr.id_prod
    WHERE o.id_order_status > 11
    AND pr.active = 1
    GROUP BY p.id_prod
    ORDER BY quantity
    LIMIT 10
```

If I use `GROUP BY p.id_prod` instead of `GROUP BY pr.id_prod` and remove the `ORDER BY`, the query is run in 0.07sec.

is that EXPLAIN table OKAY?

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  o   range   PRIMARY,id_order_status id_order_status 1       75940   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  od  ref id_order,id_prod_ref    id_order    4   dbname.o.id_order   1   
1   SIMPLE  pr  eq_ref  PRIMARY,id_prod PRIMARY 4   dbname.od.id_prod_ref   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  p   eq_ref  PRIMARY,name_url,id_brand,name  PRIMARY 4   dbname.pr.id_prod   1   Using index
```

And this is the EXPLAIN without the ORDER BY

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  p   index   PRIMARY,name_url,id_brand,name  PRIMARY 4       1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  pr  ref PRIMARY,id_prod id_prod 4   dbname.p.id_prod    2   Using where
1   SIMPLE  od  ref id_order,id_prod_ref    id_prod_ref 4   dbname.pr.id_prod_ref   67  
1   SIMPLE  o   eq_ref  PRIMARY,id_order_status PRIMARY 4   dbname.od.id_order  1   Using where
```

And here is the table structures

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
 `id_order` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_dir` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `id_status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '11',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_order`),
 KEY `id_dir` (`id_dir`),
 KEY `id_status` (`id_status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `orders_details` (
 `id_order_det` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_order` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `id_prod_ref` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `quantity` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_order_det`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id_order` (`id_order`,`id_prod_ref`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `id_prod_ref` (`id_prod_ref`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `products` (
 `id_prod` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_prod`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `products_references` (
 `id_prod_ref` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_prod` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `stock` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `dt_add` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_prod_ref`),
 KEY `id_prod` (`id_prod`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I also tried to give you the tables relations (ON UPDATE, ON DELETE CASCADE, ...) but didn't manage to export it. But I don't think it's crucial for now!

Comment: Why group by a column not in the SELECT? GROUP BY p.id_prod is the correct way

Comment: Thanks Mihai for your fast reply too :) Well, even if I use pr.id_prod in the SELECT, it wont change something anything :/

Comment: OK,put an EXPLAIN before your query and edit your question with the results

Comment: as I said in my initial post, I tried to put the EXPLAIN but it was completely a mess. is there a way to better copy paste it?

Comment: Copy it as a table or a similar option from your mysql client.

Comment: Please tell me if you can read the EXPLAIN, otherwise I'll find another way.

Comment: Whoa!  There is no column `id_order_status`??  Perhaps you meant `id_status`?

Comment: Yes you're right, just a mistake in writing :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using  the alias name in order by  and not the value from the table

and use the group by for the value in select (is the same for join because is inner  join on equal value and  the value form the pr is not retrived  for select result   )

```
 SELECT p.id_prod, p.name, SUM(od.quantity) AS quantity
 FROM orders AS o
 INNER JOIN orders_details AS od ON od.id_order = o.id_order
 INNER JOIN products_references AS pr ON pr.id_prod_ref = od.id_prod_ref
 INNER JOIN products AS p ON p.id_prod = pr.id_prod
 WHERE pr.active = 1
 GROUP BY p.id_prod
 ORDER BY quantity
 LIMIT 10
```

do not forget to use appropriate indexes on join columns

Comment: thank you scaisEdge for your very fast reply :)
Sorry my bad, I'm already using the alias name. I corrected my initial post.

Comment: OK but using  p.id_prod  you should improve your performance because so you don't need  the retrieve  of the  pr.id_prod ..  values .. . and last  you need  proper index on your join columns ..

Comment: indeed, using p.id_prod in GROUP BY improves significantly the performance when there is no ORDER BY, but sorry, I still dont understand why!

all the columns used in JOIN are indexed. I use innoDB and set all the transactions between the indexed columns

Comment: Is simple  .. if you use p.id_prod .. the query access on the same "info" that use for the rest of query  .. if  you use the group by  pr.id_prod  these values must be addittionally retrive by the query engine for buil the infor needed  by order by  ... so with pr.di_prod  you ask for more data to the data and the query engine work  a alor of  more  ..

Comment: OK, but what if I use SELECT pr.id_prod and then GROUP BY pr.id_prod ? will that be OK?

Comment: If you select pr.prod_id  and group by the same column  you should obtain the same result with only group by pr.prod_id  because you have .name  in your select .. so you access to 2 resource ... if not you access  on to 1 resource .. clear ?

Comment: OTOH, the  Optimizer is _usually_ smart enough to see that the values are the same, based on `p.id_prod = pr.id_prod`.

Answer (score 0):

(Rewritten after OP added more info.)

```
SELECT  pr.id_prod,
        MAX(pr.stock) AS max_stock,
        MAX(pr.dt_add) AS max_dt_add
        SUM(od.quantity) AS sum_quantity
    FROM  orders AS o
    INNER JOIN  orders_details AS od
            ON od.id_order = o.id_order
    INNER JOIN  products_references AS pr
            ON pr.id_prod_ref = od.id_prod_ref
    WHERE  o.id_order_status > 11
      AND  pr.active = 1
    GROUP BY  pr.id_prod
    ORDER BY  sum_quantity
    LIMIT  10
```

Note that `p` was removed as being irrelevant.

Beware of `SUM()` when using `JOIN` with `GROUP BY` -- you *might* get an incorrect, inflated, value.

Improvement on one table:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders_details` (
 `id_order` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `id_prod_ref` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `quantity` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_order`,`id_prod_ref`),
 INDEX (id_prod_ref, id_order)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Here's why:  `od` sounds like a many:many mapping table.  See [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for tips on improving performance in it.

`GROUP BY` *usually* involves a sort.  `ORDER BY`, when it is not identical to the `GROUP BY` definitely requires another sort.

Removing the `ORDER BY` allows the query to return any 10 rows without the sort.  (This may explain the timing difference.)

Note the alias `sum_quantity` to avoid ambiguity between the *column* `quantity` and your *alias* `quantity`.

**Explaining EXPLAIN**

```
1   SIMPLE  o   range   id_order_status 1                75940   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  od  ref     id_order        4   o.id_order       1   
1   SIMPLE  pr  eq_ref  PRIMARY         4   od.id_prod_ref   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  p   eq_ref  PRIMARY         4   pr.id_prod       1   Using index
```

- The tables will be accessed in the order given (o,od,pr,p).
- `o` won't use the data ("Using index") but will scan the `id_order_status` index which includes `(id_status, id_order)`.  Note:  The `PRIMARY KEY` columns are *implicitedly* added to any secondary key.
- It *estimates* 76K will need to be scanned (for > 11).
- Somewhere in the processing, there will a temp table and a sort of it.  This may *or may not* involve disk I/O.
- The reach into `od` might find 1 row, might find 0 or more than 1 ("ref").
- The reaching into `pr` and `p` are known to get at most 1 row.
- `pr` does a small amount of filtering (`active=1`), but not until the third line of `EXPLAIN`.  And no index is useful for this filtering.  This could be improved, but only slightly, by a composite index `(active, id_prod_ref)`.  With only 5-10% being filtered out, this won't help much.
- After all the `JOINing` and filtering, there will be *two* temp tables and sorts, one for `GROUP BY`, one for `ORDER BY`.
- Only after that, will 10 rows be peeled off from the 70K (or so) rows collected up to this point.

Without the ORDER BY, the `EXPLAIN` shows that a different order seems to be better.  And the tmp & sort went away.

```
1   SIMPLE  p   index   PRIMARY     4                     1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  pr  ref     id_prod     4   p.id_prod         2   Using where
1   SIMPLE  od  ref     id_prod_ref 4   pr.id_prod_ref   67  
1   SIMPLE  o   eq_ref  PRIMARY     4   dbne.od.id_order  1   Using where
```

- There seem to be only `1` row in `p`, correct?  So, in a way, it does not matter when this table is accessed.  When you have multiple "products" all this analysis may change!
- "key=PRIMARY", "Using index" is sort of a misnomer.  It is really using the data, but being able to efficiently access it because the `PRIMARY KEY` is "clustered" with the data.
- There is only one `pr` row??  Perhaps the optimizer realized that `GROUP BY` was not needed?
- When it got to `od`, it estimated that "67" rows would be needed per p+pr combo.
- You removed the `ORDER BY`, so there is no need to sort, and *any* 10 rows can be delivered.

Comment: Hi Rick and thanks for your reply.

Actually, I need to join the tables products and orders because i retrieve some values form them! and even with the query you mentionned, it's still very slow, about 0.7s :/ and if I remove the ORDER BY, 0.04s.

I will edit my initial post with the SHOW CREATE TABLE

Comment: Knowing what fields you will fetch makes a difference!

Comment: I have updated my post with the tables structure. Hope it's all clear by now :)

Comment: I overhauled my Answer.

Comment: Thank you rick, I'll check it out tomorrow. Whatever the result is, I want to thank you and all the stackoverflow community for your irreproachable help in this matter... :) cheers

Comment: good day rick,I have tested your code but it doesn't change much :/ I can't change the table "orders_details" structure as I must have the column id_order_det as PK and autoincrement :( Do you know why in the EXPLAIN the table orders_details doesn't recognise the PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: any clues for this problem?

Comment: "must have id_order_dt as PK"??  Some other table using it?  If so, elaborate on its use.  3rd party software creating it?  Now that it is created, you can change it.

Comment: What was the EXPLAIN for my version?

Comment: I need id_order_det in my code to target this specific line in the cart. And changing it implies changing a lot in my scripts :( i didn't have the chance to do a EXPLAIN to your query as I wasn't able to apply your structure!

Comment: As a compromise, change KEY `id_prod_ref` (`id_prod_ref`) to `KEY(id_prod_ref, id_order)`

Comment: I have just changed the KEY, but it doesn't change nothing! :( 
P.S. having already UNIQUE KEY `id_order` (`id_order`,`id_prod_ref`) isn't enough? what's the difference between this UNIQUE KEY index and the one you asked me to add?

Comment: `INDEX(a,b)` and `INDEX(b,a)` _are different_.  `UNIQUE(...)` is (1) and index and (2) a uniqueness constraint; so the `INDEX` is redundant.

Comment: OK thanks for the explanation. so do you think there is anyway to optimize the query and/or the tables? for now i cache the results with PHP to prevent querying the db very often, but I'm very surprised that such a small query can't return results in much less time!!

Comment: How big is each table?

Comment: products: 1k, products_references: 6k, orders: 150k, orders_details: 480k

Comment: Very few orders have a product_reference??

Comment: actually all the orders have at least 1 product_reference

Comment: What fraction of orders have `o.id_order_status > 11`?  What fraction of prod_ref have `pr.active = 1`?  (I'm wondering if it is worth getting the `SUM(quantity)` for all combinations, _then_ apply those two filters.

Comment: Well, since it's a query to get the best sellers, I need to make sure the product isn't removed and also that the order has been shipped or delivered.. :)

Comment: Umm, I guess there is no solution for this except cache the content to reduce mysql queries??? :/

Comment: Are you saying that _most_ rows have order_status>11 and active=1 ?

Comment: all selected rows have order_status > 11 and active = 1 which means all orders shipped with products not removed! how avec in the database, i have a lot order_status = 11 which i don't need to select them!

Comment: No, I am asking what percentage of the table is filtered by each.  Since the  two columns are in different tables, a different solution is needed depending on which filters better.

Comment: Ah ok, order_status = 11 may represent about 40%, it's basically all the saved carts or non finalized orders

Comment: And what percent for `active = 1`?

Comment: Active = 1 is about 90 or 95%